# Windows live mail places all tables in 1 row, instead beneath eachother

Tags: php, html-table, html-email, windows-live-mail

*Edit: Added example below.*

I have the following code (simplified for example) which I send as newsletter:

```
<table width="700">
    <tr>
        <td width="700"><!-- Really trying to set 700 as max) -->

            <table width="700"> <!-- simple table content, not bigger than 700 --></table>
            <table width="350"> <!-- simple table content, not bigger than 350 --></table>
            <table width="350"> <!-- simple table content, not bigger than 350 --></table>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Expected result:**
`[------  table 700 ------]`
`[ table 350 ][ table 350 ]`

**Result in Windows Live Mail:**  (working fine in Mac's Mail)
`[------  table 700 ------][ table 350 ][ table 350 ]`

It's all in 1 row, though the wrapping TD and table are set to 700, I'm expected it starting on new lines.

I can not add breaks, this is dynamic code, I have more parts, and I dont know in the code which is the last of a line.

I can't find topics about this, other than "start sending mails, with tables"-novice solutions.

**Anyone got a clue?**

Comment: For the few actually viewing this page, it has something to do with `align="left"`. I remove that, everything drops beneath eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem/solution is using `align="left"`. Any table with `align=left` will have the next table stuck to it. Example of prefered result:

`[---- 100  ----]`
`[--50--][--50--]`
`[25][25][25][25]`

If all those tables have `align="left"`, it would result in one long line:

`[---- 100  ----][--50--][--50--][25][25][25][25]`

I removed the `align=left` from the first table, which results like this:

`[---- 100  ----]`
`[--50--][--50--][25][25][25][25]`

I can'r remove the `align=left` from the other tables, because I want those inline-block. In order to get them properly, I added a 'split' in my code. The split-table is a table without the `align=left` and no height. All tables haves `align=left`, apart from the split:

`[---- 100  ----](split)`
`[--50--][--50--](split)`
`[25][25][25][25]`

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display:block;"` to your top table.

However you'd be better off putting them into their own `<td>`'s instead of float/aligning them there.

Like this:

```
<table width="700" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#eeeeee">
      ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="350" bgcolor="#cccccc">
            ...
          </td>
          <td width="350" bgcolor="#dddddd">
            ...
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666877/email-newsletter-rendering-issues-in-outlook-2010/22669238#22669238) that explains another issue you'd likely face with aligning tables like you have.

If you are trying to go responsive, you can use `<td>`'s with `display:block;` instead to make them 'pop' down when the media query triggers. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22614437/html-email-looking-different-in-gmail-app/22615527#22615527)

Comment: It's not responsive. Im only talking about windows live mail, all others are find. I agree with the `wrap in td's` solution, but that simple isn't an option, the parts are dynamic in the sense that I the order could shuffle. Im going to try the block trick, ill let you know

Comment: Giving the table `display:block;` has no influence whatsoever

Comment: I just noticed have a typo in the parent `<td>` - you have `with` not `width`, which could be the cause.

Comment: I double checked, only in this example :) The original code is fine

Comment: I'm surprised the `display:block;` didn't work. Try adding `align="left"` to the tables also. This should overflow them. If that doesn't work, option B in the code demo I posted will definitely work. That is the most consistent way to do it in html email.

Comment: I never noticed, I'm allready using `align="left"` in all the blocks, and the table which containts the parts